# How to prevent double clinch?

Tags: ufc-undisputed-2010

GSP did that to me, I was BJ. I was holding back all the time, he clinched me once and I have blocked it, but the second time he got the clinch(I did not release the holding back button). he did it 3 times in our fight, so its not an accident, but technique/exploit.

Comment: I haven't had this happen, but there is some good advice in [this thread](http://community.ufcundisputed.com/forums/topic/7481)